# Create subdomain for each user dynamically (in a shared server)

Tags: apache, subdomain, httpd.conf

i want to create subdomains automatically for each user, like: `user1.example.com`, `user2.example.com`, `user3.example.com` .....

First i created an **"A record"** like `*.example.com IN A 1.2.3.4.` second i learned i need to create a virtual hosting. However i am on a shared server which means i don't have access to `httpd.conf` file. if i type `jjj.example.com` it directly goes to `jjj.example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi.`

What should i do after that point? Can i create what i want on a shared server? Should i give up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mhh - what do you want exactly?

1. Create different subdomains which shall be handled on different
   ip-Adresses (by different parts of Software)
2. Adjust yout (Web-)Server zu deliver user- (=subdomain-) specific contents?

Comment: i just want a site like tumblr. user will choose a name llike `examp`. and site will have a subdomain with that name like `examp.tumblr.com` instantly

Comment: @WebberDepor, Have you found the solution? I have the same issue.